# prepend function for all types in go

Tags: go

I have written a very small prepend function for go.

```
func prepend(slice []int, elms ... int) []int {

   newSlice := []int{}

   for _, elm := range elms {
      newSlice = append(newSlice, elm)
   }

   for _, item := range slice {
      newSlice = append(newSlice, item)

   }

   return newSlice
}
```

Is there anyway to make the function generic for any type?

So that I can put in a slice of arrays a prepend to that.

Also, is there a better way to write this function?

I have not found anything online about writing one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't think you can write such function in a type-generic way. But you can use `append` to prepend as well.

```
c = append([]int{b}, a...)
```

[Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/14fN5SIL9h).

Comment: if this is performance-sensitive code and/or processing large arrays, you need to be aware that this pattern may produce a ton of realloc/copy

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
// Prepend is complement to builtin append.
func Prepend(items []interface{}, item interface{}) []interface{} {
    return append([]interface{}{item}, items...)
}
```